# How to use SQLDelight together with SqlCipher (Kotlin Multiplatform)

Tags: android, kotlin, sqlcipher, koin, sqldelight

I am trying to encrypt my **SQLDelight** database using **SqlCipher**. I've found one appropriate example on [GitHub](https://github.com/softartdev/NoteDelight/tree/master), however, it uses outdated [cwac-saferoom](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom) which connects Room with SQLCipher for Android. The oudated library mentions to use [SQLCipher for Android](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher#using-sqlcipher-for-android-with-room). So, taking into consideration the NoteDelight repository from the GitHub mentioned above and the SQLCipher Android documentation I tried implementing this approach. However, I cannot seem to understand how to make this work.

1. I have followed [SQLDelight documentation](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/2.0.0/) and implemented my **.sq** files under **src/main/sqldelight** as well added necessary imports.
2. Under the **commonMain** package I have

```kotlin
expect val databaseModule: Module

val repositoriesModule = module {
    single { AddressRepository(get()) }
    // more repositories
}
```

```kotlin
class AddressRepository(private val database: Database) {

    fun insertAddress(address: Address) =
        database.addressQueries.insertAddress(
            // parameters
        )

    // more functions
}
```

3. Now in **androidMain** I provide the actual implementation of databaseModule:

```kotlin
actual val databaseModule: Module = module {
    single<Database> { AndroidDatabase(get()) }
}
```

```kotlin
abstract class DatabaseQueries {
    abstract val addressQueries: AddressQueries
    // more queries
}

abstract class Database : DatabaseQueries() {
    abstract fun initializeDatabase(passphrase: CharSequence = ""): DatabaseHolder

    // encrypt, decrypt, repass and other abstract methods
}

class AndroidDatabase(private val context: Context) : Database() {
    private var databaseHolder: DatabaseHolder? = null

    override val addressQueries: AddressQueries
        get() = initializeDatabase("").addressQueries

    override fun initializeDatabase(passphrase: CharSequence): DatabaseHolder {
        var instance = databaseHolder

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = AndroidDatabaseHolder(context, SpannableStringBuilder(passphrase))
            databaseHolder = instance
        }

        return instance
    }

    // other methods that override abstract methods
}
```

4. I implement my database holder class

```kotlin
abstract class DatabaseHolder : DatabaseQueries() {
    abstract val database: MyDatabase
    abstract val driver: SqlDriver
}


class AndroidDatabaseHolder(
    context: Context,
    passphrase: CharSequence
) : DatabaseHolder() {

    init {
        System.loadLibrary("sqlcipher")
    }

    private val encryptedDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(
        context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME),
        passphrase.toString(),
        null
    )

    override val driver = AndroidSqliteDriver(encryptedDatabase)
    override val database: MyDatabase = createQueryWrapper(driver)

    override val addressQueries: AddressQueries = database.addressQueries
    // more overriden queries

    override fun close() {
        driver.close()
    }

}
```

5. Util method

```kotlin
fun createQueryWrapper(driver: SqlDriver): MyDatabase {
    return MyDatabase(
        driver = driver,
        photoAdapter = /* My adapter */)
    )
}
```

I first open clean app and create the database using `initializeDatabase` with my provided password. Then in the login page I provide the password and the app calls the `initializeDatabase` method again. Then I get to the main page where all the repositories get all the records from the database. That's where the error occurs for each of the repository:

```kotlin
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: address: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM address
```

Is the approach I am following is correct to implement SqlCipher encryption together with SQLDelight for the best practices? Are there any examples I have missed for correct implementation? And how to fix my error? Thanks.